# Android studio 2022.3.1 , The default project fails to build

Tags: android-studio

I have been trying to run the default project of android studio (with kotlin) and it doesn't work, it gives me like 21 errors but they all seem to stem from either "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0" or "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"

I have to mention that I have no idea what I am doing, I have just started messing with android studio yesterday.
If I click on the links (for example   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.4.0/material-1.4.0.aar) then that file gets downloaded in the browser but I am not sure what to do with it.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform material-1.4.0.aar (androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find material-1.4.0.aar (androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.4.0/material-1.4.0.aar
```

```
7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform material-1.4.0.aar (androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find material-1.4.0.aar (androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/material/material/1.4.0/material-1.4.0.aar
   > Failed to transform concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar (androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=7, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar (androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/concurrent/concurrent-futures/1.1.0/concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar
```

-I tried re installing the whole program, to no avail.
-Changing the Gradle JDK from jbr-17 to Oracle Open JDK 21 and nothing happened differently.
-I changed the Kotlin complier to the latest version
-I Used "Invalidate Caches" which also didn't fix the issue
-I changed Android SDK target and compile SDK to 34 which also didn't change anything
-I tried changing "JAVA_HOME" from "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr" to "C:/Users/mgi30/.jdks/openjdk-21", this cause different errors so I undid the change after the fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

If you delete the .gradel folder at C:\Users\UserName then next time you try to run the program it will re download required data and then it worked just fine